# Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below worked well previously but unsure how this error is coming up.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
//  const LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String idScreen = "login";
  final TextEditingController nameTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController phoneTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 35.0,
              ),
              Image(
                image: AssetImage("images/images/logo.png"),
                width: 390.0,
                height: 350.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 1.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "Login as Driver",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontFamily: "Brand Bold"),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: emailTextEditingController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Email",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: passwordTextEditingController,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Password",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      //color: Colors.pink[200],
                      //textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Bold"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      //   borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (!emailTextEditingController.text.contains("@")) {
                          displayToastMessage(
                              "Email address is not valid", context);
                        } else if (passwordTextEditingController.text.isEmpty) {
                          displayToastMessage("password is not valid", context);
                        } else {
                          loginUser(context);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      context, RegistrationScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Account not found, Please register",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void loginUser(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProgressDialog(
            message: "Authenticating, Please wait...",
          );
        });
    final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailTextEditingController.text,
                password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
            .catchError((errMsg) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      driversRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
        if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
          displayToastMessage("You are logged in", context);
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _firebaseAuth.signOut();
          displayToastMessage(
              "No record exists for this user, please create a new account",
              context);
        }
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMessage("An error occured, cannot sign in", context);
    }

 
  }
}
```

I read other similar question but using the `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` in the dispose method. unsure how to do it.

The error points out at

```
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil( //here
              context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
          displayToastMessage("You are logged in", context);
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `displayToastMessage` with the `context` of a widget that has been removed from the tree and its `context` is no longer valid. For example here

```dart
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
displayToastMessage("You are logged in", context);
```

You are navigating to other screen and removing the current widget from the tree. In the next line you are calling `displayToastMessage` using the `context` of current widget which is already deactivated. The same problem occurs when using the `Navigator.pop` before `displayToastMessage`.

A solution is to call the `displayToastMessage` before navigating.

```dart
displayToastMessage("You are logged in", context);
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
```

Alternatively, you can call the `displayToastMessage` from the widget that you are navigating to.